# Ajax image uploader issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a issue with a image uploader i am making in ASP. I want to upload a image to the projects folder using ajax.

my html and js:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <br />
    <a href="#" id="btnImg" onclick="uploadImg()" runat="server">UPLOAD</a>
    </div>
    </form>

<script>
    function uploadImg(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('FileUpload1', $('#btnImg')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/imageUpload',
            data: formData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

my image upload code(c#):

```
[WebMethod]
protected void imageUpload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        Guid _fileNameRandom = Guid.NewGuid();
        string _fileNameStr = _fileNameRandom.ToString();
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/") + (_fileNameStr + fileName));
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

IN console i get the following errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at uploadImg (Default.aspx:32)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Default.aspx:21)

line 32 in default.aspx is:         }); of the js script.
and line 21 is:     function uploadImg(){

Hope anyone can help me resolve this.

Comment: This line is the problem: `$('#btnImg')[0].files[0]`, although it's not clear why exactly. Are you running this code after selecting a file?

Comment: Can you be more precise? :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#btnImg')[0]` is the culprit.

`$('#btnImg')[0]` will never have a files collection, because that's an anchor element, try changing it to `$('#FileUpload1')[0]`, and see if that works?  If not, you need to reference the `input[type='file']` element which I think the ASP helper should render for you with that id.

Comment: if i change to $('#FileUpload1')[0] i get: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation. can you be more specific with the input[type='file']? im new in this department...

Comment: Try `formData.append('FileUpload1', $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]); ` instead.  This assumes you only have one file upload control on the page.

Comment: I tryed that but still not working: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery.min.js:4)
    at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at uploadImg (Default.aspx:33)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Default.aspx:21)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, to **Show** the image and **Upload** the image:

HTML:

```
<label asp-for="Image"></label>
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="ShowImage(this)" name="file" />
<input type="button" id="but_upload" class="button" value="Upload">
<img src="#" id="imgBox" class="img-responsive" width="100%"/>
```

js:

Show the image

```
function ShowImage(input) {       
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {        
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgBox').attr("src", e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Upload the image:

```
var fd = new FormData();
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#but_upload').click(function () {
    var file = $("#FileUpload").get(0).files;
    if (file != undefined) {
       fd.append('fillle', file[0]);
    }
    else {
        alert("undefined");
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Person/UploadFile",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert(data.message);                    
            }
            else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

C# code:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
//It needs to inject to the constructor
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile fillle)
    {
        string wwwRoothPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        if (fillle != null)
        {
            string fileName = "TempFile"; // Or: Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var upload = Path.Combine(wwwRoothPath, @"images\Person"); //First make a folder Person in images route
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(fillle.FileName);

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fillle.CopyTo(filestream);
            }

            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Image Uploaded Succesfully" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error Uploading File" });
        }
    }
```

I hope this would be useful.